# Prolog finding a integer complement in a list

Tags: list, prolog

Given a sorted, no duplicates list L I would like to find out if it has at least one pair of complementary integers (i.e. <-1,1>, <-2,2>, etc.)

I am puzzled how to structure this one functionally in prolog. Essentially what I want to do is iterate through each negative number one by one and check if its complement (positive number digit) exists in the list. Normally this would be a double loop in other languages but how could I do this in Prolog?

Here's what I have so far but I am curious if there is a more elegant solution without using a control statement...

```
findint(X,[X|_]).
findint(X,[_|Tail]) :- findint(X,Tail).

findpair([X|Tail]) :- X < 0, Y is -1*X, (findint(Y,Tail) -> true ; findpair(Tail)).
```

Comment: Try starting from a logical formulation: there exists X,Y such that both are elements of the list, and X is the complement of Y.

Comment: Since the list is sorted, you only need to check the elements up to and including `0` to see if its arithmetic inverse (what you're calling its compliment) is a member of the rest of the list.

Answer (score 0):

a 'trick of the trade': use member/2 instead of iteration

```
complement_integers(L, I1,I2) :-
    member(I1,L),
    member(I2,L),
    I1 =:= -I2.
```